# In Exodus 13:17, is the uncertainty of outcome part of the meaning of the Hebrew word 'peradventure'/'might' is serving as translation of?

Tags: hebrew, word-study, exodus

Exodus 13:17 reads, in my Bible:

> And it came to pass, when Pharaoh had let the people go, that God led them not *through* the way of the land of the Philistines, although that *was* near; for God said, Lest peradventure the people repent when they see war, and they return to Egypt:

In looking through several translations, they all use 'might' or 'peradventure' to translate the relevant Hebrew passage.  In English both those words mean something like "maybe they will do this, and maybe they won't": a situation where the outcome is uncertain.  Is this sense present within the Hebrew text as well?

Comment: Welcome to BHSE! Make sure you take our Tour. (See "?", upper right). Thanks

Comment: @JohnMartin Did you know that if you type \[tour\] it makes a hyperlink for you?  The same is true for \[help\]. [tour] [help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hebrew it is not exactly the same: the word 'פן' is in a sentence when someone does something in order to Prevent something from happening. God led them not through the way of the land of the Philistines... (so that) they (will not) see war, and (will not) return to Egypt. He did so for (if He would have not done so) they **might** think of returning.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Would it make sense to explain a bit more in your answer why that Hebrew word is translated as "might" rather then "would"?

Comment: "I gathered the herd quickly because it may get lost." (אספתי במהירות את העדר **פן** יאבד) It may or may not get lost, but I did something to prevent it from getting lost. In such sentence the word (פן) comes instead of 'because (it) may'. I don't know of a parallel word in English. 'Might' is the closest. (Example for a sentence which you can **not** use this word: "The herd may be thirsty")

Comment: Oh okay!  I think I get it; פן doesn't mean that the thing would or would not happen with certainty but rather that the action is done to prevent some possible consequence.  You could say "I took the bread out of the oven so that it would not burn", even though it would burn with certainty, or "He opened the door so that the room would not be hot" even if he knew it was probably hotter outside and so the plan was unlikely to work.  We don't use 'would' because the phrase doesn't convey that the course of action will necessarily ensure the desired outcome, merely that it has preventitive intent

Comment: Almost... I just don't understand why you added the bad consequence in the examples you wrote. 'פן' means I do something and it will really prevent something from happening. It **does** affect (or is supposed to affect) the consequence. In your examples- "I took the bread out of the oven so that it would not burn". it was ''may or may not'', and now because I did something - took it out, it will (probably) **not** burn. Now I am interested to know if you understood..